# Cambiar variable de character a numeric

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una variable (`deciles_ingreso`) en tipo `character` y necesito pasarla a numérica, siguiendo este camino me da error, pero no se como hacerlo

```
is.character(base$ingreso_quintil)
base$ingreso_quintil=as.numeric(base$ingreso_quintil)
View(base$ingreso_quintil)
```

y esto hace que toda la variable cambie a "NA", o sea no me es útil que camino debo seguir.

Los datos:

```
str(base$ingreso_per_capita_quintil) 
chr [1:2961] "Quinto quintil" "Cuarto quintil" "Primer quintil" "Primer quintil" "Primer quintil"
```

Comment: Agrega una muestra de los datos, por ejemplo la salida del comando `str(base`)

Comment: str(base$ingreso_per_capita_quintil)  - de la varible que me genera problema- 
chr [1:2961] "Quinto quintil" "Cuarto quintil" "Primer quintil" "Primer quintil" "Primer quintil" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes en `ingreso_per_capita_quintil`es un vector de caracteres pero con estos valores:

```
"Quinto quintil" "Cuarto quintil" "Primer quintil" "Primer quintil" "Primer quintil"
```

un `as.numeric()` no tiene la lógica para transformarlos en números, por que de hecho no lo son. Lo que puedes hacer es  pivotear con un `factor` para hacer los reemplazos por un número del 1 al 5 por "Primer quintil" al "Quinto quintil". Por ejemplo:

```
as.numeric(factor(base$ingreso_per_capita_quintil, 
                  levels=c("Primer quintil", "Segundo quintil", "Tercer quintil",
                           "Cuarto quintil", "Quinto quintil")
                 )
           )
```